# How was this High-Resolution Short-Wave Infrared image captured?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, portrait, infrared

The Wikipedia article on [Infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) contains a [comparison image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Infrared_portrait_comparison.jpg) showing how a portrait looks when shot in various wavelengths.

While searching for information on SWIR, I've read that normal sensors are not sensitive to that spectrum range and that various industrial-grade cameras exist but with a quite low (< 1 MP) resolution.

So here comes the question: How was the 8 MP SWIR image from Wikipedia captured? Is it perhaps an edit of an image captured in a different wavelength, or do more affordable solutions exist for capturing high resolution images in the 1500-1700nm range?

[image: Infrared portrait comparison]

Comment: How do you know it's an 8MP image?

Comment: @BobT Probably because it is roughly one third of a composite image that is around 30MP?

Comment: @D. Jurcau What about the image makes you think it was taken with a 'more affordable' solution?

Comment: The resolution similar to that of consumer cameras leads me to think of something consumer oriented (with accent on artistic looks rather than precise measurements). Then again, I might be wrong.

Comment: The composite image metadata as listed on the Wikimedia site indicates that the image was taken with a Sony Alpha A7. I don't think looking at the size of the image and dividing by 3 is a good indicator of resolution in this case...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I can tell you I definitely didn't take it with my Sony A7.  I think Photoshop pulls the metadata when you lay the images side by side from what it can find.

The visible and NIR images were taken with my converted A7.  The SWIR camera is from a company that is currently working on a gallium on silicon coating process so they can use somewhat traditional manufacturing processes and deliver a more affordable SWIR solution.  They contracted me to take some images with it for their marketing campaign.

Definitely let me know if you have any more questions and I'd be glad to answer them!  You can also find more information in this [more detailed post](https://www.nickspiker.com/photographing-invisible-light/).

[image: SWIR camera and Sony A7 on top to collect NIR, visible and UV photographs along with SWIR photographs]

Comment: Welcome Nick, glad you're here.  Thanks for the great answer about how you made this particular image.  I edited your post a bit to clarify the nature of the link.  

Also, this is a bit different from forums, so we [don't normally use signatures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) since your profile is linked as your signature automatically.  You can add whatever details you want to your profile itself and people will be able to access it.